# Finding partial properties

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, in-memory

I have a Map. Key contains 6 character String and Properties class roughly looks like below :

```
public class Properties {
    private String propertyOne;
    private String propertyTwo;
    private String propertyThree;
    private String propertyFour;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now let's say I have some entries in the map as below :

> 41111 -> {1,2,3,4,5}
>
> 41112 -> {1,2,3,4,6}
>
> 41234 -> {1,2,345,87,65}
>
> 51123 -> {100,200,30000,345,123}
>
> 51122 -> {100,200,30000,556,989}

Now, if I do `map.get("12567")`, I get the desired property object.

The challenge I have is, I have to create a data structure which can save the partial data. By partial data I mean if I do `map.get("4111")` I should get the **intersection** of `{1,2,3,4,5}` **(property for 41111)** and `{1,2,3,4,6}` **(property for 41112)** which is `{1,2,3,4,null}.`

Similarly `map.get("41")` should produce `{1,2,null,null,null}`.

I right now have a solution which is, I have created multiple HashMaps which contain all possible partial keys and their corresponding values like :

``` Map<String, Property>`` keyValuesForOneChar ```  contains all possible single characters as keys and their corresponding values.

`Map<String, Property> keyValuesForTwoChars` contains all possible two characters  as keys and their corresponding values.

I did not like this solution as it's pretty much straight forward and I don't think maintaining multiple hashmaps is a good idea. One more problem is that my raw data count is around 200000 and with all permutation combinations I would be creating huge partial data and with that huge count I think the performance of hashmaps decreases. Please suggest a better solution for this problem. I have the following constraints :

1. The solution should strictly be a in-memory only.
2. The look-up should be faster. That's why if the processing of the raw data and preparing the data structure takes extra time and memory that should not be a problem.

Comment: For @T. Clarverie answer it would be interesting if it is required to find "11" as key which should then intersect 41111, 41112, 51123 and 51122 or does the search always start from the beginning of the key?

Comment: it should always start from beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HashMap is definitely not the most suited data structure to your problem. As your keys are strings, you can implement a trie (also called prefix tree).

It works by splitting the string keys into smaller strings or character. This way you can store values for the keys, but also for common prefixes. That is, you can store the intersection of "41111" and "41112" on the common prefix "4111". When looking up for 4111, it takes O(m) steps where m is the length of the key, and you would be able to retrieve the intersection of {1,2,3,4,5} and {1,2,3,4,6} if you update intersections as you insert items in the trie.

**Retrieve partial properties**

You can update partial properties while constructing the trie. Let's say that you insert the couple (41111, {1,2,3,4,5}). Tries are specific trees, and it can look like this. The notation `k,v` means that this is a node with key `k` and value `v`.

```
4,{1,2,3,4,5}
      |
1,{1,2,3,4,5}
      |
1,{1,2,3,4,5}
      |
1,{1,2,3,4,5}
      |
1,{1,2,3,4,5}
```

On each node along the path, you store a partial property. Now, when inserting the couple (41112,{1,2,3,4,6}), you update the trie:

```
       4,{1,2,3,4,null}
             |
       1,{1,2,3,4,null}
             |
       1,{1,2,3,4,null}
             |
       1,{1,2,3,4,null}
      /                \
1,{1,2,3,4,5}     2,{1,2,3,4,6}
```

And again, if you insert 41234,{1,2,345,87,65}, it will look like this:

```
              4,{1,2,null,null,null}
                         |
              1,{1,2,null,null,null}
             /                      \
       1,{1,2,3,4,null}          2,{1,2,345,87,65}
             |                           |
       1,{1,2,3,4,null}          3,{1,2,345,87,65}
      /                \                 | 
1,{1,2,3,4,5}     2,{1,2,3,4,6}  4,{1,2,345,87,65}
```

Doing this, you store partial properties only for the common prefixes of the item that are already inserted, you do not need to create all combinations. Plus, retrieving the partial properties is done using the same algorithm tha retrieving the values.

Comment: totally agree.. now I dont have to finish my answer^^. Hashmap (any map implementation) is the completely wrong data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But the problem still lies in getting the partial properties. That still I have manually go through each record and find it out. So, the approach goes like this :
First manually find all possible partial data and then prepare the Trie.

Comment: I added an example of what I had in mind, and this is more efficient than keeping 6 different HashMap and to compute all possible combinations and partial properties.

Comment: Just one last doubt. Will the retrieval operation for Trie take more time than a HashMap as I can see, to get property for any key I have to traverse from one node to another where as for HashMap it will be just an index based retrieval (provided my hash function is that efficient).

Comment: That's an interesting question. From my experience, I benchmarked a basic trie (not optimized) against java's HashMap and my trie was a few percents less efficient than a hashmap on randomized sequence of put/get/delete. (Though the keys were longer ~ 15-20 chars). So, my answer is: I don't know, you need to benchmark it to get an answer. But with a correct implementation, I'm confident that you won't have a crazy performance loss. And with some optimizations, you can most probably compete with a HashMap.

Comment: I'll try both approaches and extrapolate my results and see which is more feasible as my raw data count might increase in future